# How to install libcrypt.so.2?

Tags: python, executable, shared-library, tkinter

I've got a tkinter executable. When launching from the terminal, I've got an error complaining about a missing `libcrypt.so.2`.

I don´t know what this library is used for but it's needed apparently for this executable.
I couldn't find the package where this library can be.
Any idea?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I´m on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? From where you "got a tkinter executable"? Which python version do you plan to use?

Comment: `libxcrypt*` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxcrypt&searchon=names .... Fedora is using the name `libcrypt.so.2` for "libcrypt.so.1".

Comment: @KnudLarsen How can I install libxcrypt? `apt install libxcrypt` says it can't locate it?

Comment: Please read / follow the above link https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxcrypt&searchon=names to know that for Ubuntu 20.04 only the source code is available. Build the lib, and copy "libcrypt.so.1" to `libcrypt.so.2` .